# EPPLUS: Length of a DataValidation list cannot exceed 255 characters

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

This question is answered on a basic level on another post: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197219/exceptionthe-total-length-of-a-datavalidation-list-cannot-exceed-255-characters) However for my case I am not able to hard code the validation values into the sheet I am pulling them from a database based on the content of the cell and will need to do a separate validation for 4 columns on every row. Is there a way this can be achieved? Thank you in advance.

```
    // Data Validations //
            // Product Validation // 
            for (int i = 2; i < rowCount; i++)
            {
                var val = ws.DataValidations.AddListValidation(ws.Cells[i, 5].Address);
                val.ShowErrorMessage = true;
                val.ErrorTitle = "Entry was invalid.";
                val.Error = "Please choose options from the drop down only.";

                var ticketEntity = ticketQueryable.Where(o => o.TTSTicketNumber == ws.Cells[i, 3].Value.ToString()).Single<CustCurrentTicketEntity>();

                var prodIds = prodExtQueryable.Where(p => p.ZoneId == ticketEntity.ZoneId && p.TicketTypeId == ticketEntity.TicketTypeId);

                if (ticketEntity != null)
                {
                    var prodIdsList = new List<int>();
                    foreach (var prodId in prodIds)
                    {
                        prodIdsList.Add(prodId.ProductId);
                    }
                    var ProductList = ProductCache.Instance.AllProducts.Where(p => prodIdsList.Contains(p.ProductId)).Select(p => new SelectListItem() { Value = p.ProductId.ToString(), Text = p.Name });

                    foreach (var Result in ProductList)
                    {
                        var product = Result.Text;
                        val.Formula.Values.Add(product);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why couldnt you create a second (hidden?) sheet and put the values there?  I get you want to avoid doing that but if there isnt an "excel" way of doing something Epplus will unfortunately not be able to do anything since the xml it creates has to be compliant with what excel-proper can do.  Only other thing I can think of is VBA which gets messy due to the security elevation that is needed.

Comment: @Ernie Thanks! I just now saw this response and this is what I ended up doing yesterday. I posted my Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes as Ernie said What I did was add a second sheet "ProductValidations" and set it to Hidden (unhide it to check that it is working). I then Load my data from the DataTable and then add some basic EPPLUS formatting. I then iterate over the Rows and Insert values into the "ProductValidations" sheet for each cell. Next I convert my column number to the correct Excel Column letter name (A, AC, BCE etc) I then create a string to pass back as an Excel formula targeting the correct range of cells in the "ProductValidations" sheet. Also to anyone having an issue downloading the Excel file from the server this guid method works just fine for me.

```
    public ActionResult DownloadExcel(EntityReportModel erModel, string filename)
    {
        var dataResponse = iEntityViewService.LoadEntityView(new EntityViewInput
        {
            SecurityContext = SessionCache.Instance.SecurityContext,
            EntityViewName = "Ticket",
            Parameters = new Dictionary<string, object> {
                {"MinTicketDateTime", "04/26/16"}
            }
        });

        var table = dataResponse.DataSet.Tables[0];
        filename = "TICKETS-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--hh-mm-ss") + ".xlsx";

        using (ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(filename);
            //Add second sheet to put Validations into
            ExcelWorksheet productVal = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("ProductValidations");
            // Hide Validation Sheet
            productVal.Hidden = OfficeOpenXml.eWorkSheetHidden.Hidden;
            // Load the data from the datatable 
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(table, true);
            ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

            int columnCount = table.Columns.Count;
            int rowCount = table.Rows.Count;

            // Format Worksheet// 
            ws.Row(1).Style.Font.Bold = true;

            List<string> deleteColumns = new List<string>() {
                "CurrentTicketId",
                };
            List<string> dateColumns = new List<string>() {
                "TicketDateTime",
                "Updated",
                "InvoiceDate"
                };

            ExcelRange r;

            // Format Dates
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
            {
                // if cell header value matches a date column
                if (dateColumns.Contains(ws.Cells[1, i].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    r = ws.Cells[2, i, rowCount + 1, i];
                    r.AutoFitColumns();
                    r.Style.Numberformat.Format = @"mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm";
                }
            }
              // Delete Columns
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++)
            {
                // if cell header value matches a delete column
                if ((ws.Cells[1, i].Value != null) && deleteColumns.Contains(ws.Cells[1, i].Value.ToString()))
                {
                    ws.DeleteColumn(i);
                }
            }

            int col = 0;
            int Prow = 0;
            int valRow = 1;
            // Data Validations //
            // Iterate over the Rows and insert Validations
            for (int i = 2; i-2 < rowCount; i++)
            {
                Prow = 0;
                col++;
                valRow++;
                // Add Validations At this row in column 7 //
                var ProdVal = ws.DataValidations.AddListValidation(ws.Cells[valRow, 7].Address);

                ProdVal.ShowErrorMessage = true;
                ProdVal.ErrorTitle = "Entry was invalid.";
                ProdVal.Error = "Please choose options from the drop down only.";
                var ticketEntity = ticketQueryable.Where(o => o.TTSTicketNumber == ws.Cells[i, 3].Value.ToString()).Single<CustCurrentTicketEntity>();
                // Product Validation // 
                var prodIds = prodExtQueryable.Where(p => p.ZoneId == ticketEntity.ZoneId && p.TicketTypeId == ticketEntity.TicketTypeId);

                if (ticketEntity != null)
                {
                    var prodIdsList = new List<int>();
                    foreach (var prodId in prodIds)
                    {
                        prodIdsList.Add(prodId.ProductId);
                    }
                    var ProductList = ProductCache.Instance.AllProducts.Where(p => prodIdsList.Contains(p.ProductId)).Select(p => new SelectListItem() { Value = p.ProductId.ToString(), Text = p.Name });
                    //For Each Item in the list move the row forward and add that value to the Validation Sheet
                    foreach (var Result in ProductList)
                    {
                        Prow++;
                        var product = Result.Text;
                            productVal.Cells[Prow, col].Value = product;
                    }

                    // convert column name from a number to the Excel Letters i.e A, AC, BCE//
                    int dividend = col;
                    string columnName = String.Empty;
                    int modulo;

                    while (dividend > 0)
                    {
                        modulo = (dividend - 1) % 26;
                        columnName = Convert.ToChar(65 + modulo).ToString() + columnName;
                        dividend = (int)((dividend - modulo) / 26);
                    }

                    // Pass back to sheeet as an Excel Formula to get around the 255 Char limit for Validations// 
                    string productValidationExcelFormula = "ProductValidations!" + columnName + "1:" + columnName + Prow;
                    ProdVal.Formula.ExcelFormula = productValidationExcelFormula;
                }
            }

            // Save File //
            var fileStream = new MemoryStream(pack.GetAsByteArray());
            string handle = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            fileStream.Position = 0;
            TempData[handle] = fileStream.ToArray();
            // Note we are returning a filename as well as the handle
            return new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = new { FileGuid = handle, FileName = filename }
            };
        }
    }
    [HttpGet]
            public virtual ActionResult Download(string fileGuid, string fileName)
            {
                if (TempData[fileGuid] != null)
                {
                    byte[] data = TempData[fileGuid] as byte[];
                    return File(data, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileName);
                }
                else
                {
                //Log err
                    return new EmptyResult();
                }
            }
```

Comment: I did this make 4 sheets and Pass 4 validation forumlas back and it all works.